# Running shell script through gradle

Tags: android, shell, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

So I have a shell script ready to be ran by gradle. Problem is I don't know how to run the shell script.. I wish to run the script when my application is being built. This is first time messing with the build system.. I looked at creating a task but that doesn't seem to be invoked from the app/build.gradle file:

```
task runShellScript(type:Exec) {
doLast {
    println 'Shell Script finished'
}
executable './shell-script'
```

Comment: Did you check on https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html ?

Answer (score 1):

Create the task in `build.gradle` as:

```
task task_name(type: Exec) {
          commandLine './shell_script_name.sh'  
}
```

And run as:

```
gradle task_name
```